# Simplify jQuery target CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm currently using the following jQuery JavaScript to append some HTML to an "li" tag inside the "mobile-menu" class when the "sub-menu" class exists:

```
$('.mobile-menu > li:has(ul.sub-menu)').append('<div class="menu-expand"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></div>');
```

I want to apply it for all li tags no matter how far buried inside they are, I'm currently using the following code which works fine but I'm sure there must be a way to simplify it?

```
$('.mobile-menu > li:has(ul.sub-menu)').append('<div class="menu-expand"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></div>');
$('.mobile-menu > li li:has(ul.sub-menu)').append('<div class="menu-expand"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></div>');
$('.mobile-menu > li li li:has(ul.sub-menu)').append('<div class="menu-expand"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></div>');
$('.mobile-menu > li li li li:has(ul.sub-menu)').append('<div class="menu-expand"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></div>');
$('.mobile-menu > li li li li li:has(ul.sub-menu)').append('<div class="menu-expand"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></div>');
$('.mobile-menu > li li li li li li:has(ul.sub-menu)').append('<div class="menu-expand"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></div>');
```

Any help much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't the last five selectors in that list match the same elements ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use the direct child selector (`>`)

Use:

```
$('.mobile-menu li:has(ul.sub-menu)').append('<div class="menu-expand"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></div>');
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew it'd be something simple like this :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
// to append all ul having sub-menu class
if($('.mobile-menu > li ul.sub-menu').length) {
   $('.mobile-menu > li ul.sub-menu')
       .append('<div class="menu-expand"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></div>');
}
```

And if there is nesting of ul-li-ul then use **[:nth-last-child-selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-last-child-selector/)** like,

```
$('.mobile-menu > li ul.sub-menu:nth-last-child(0)') // for the last selector
       .append('<div class="menu-expand"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></div>');
```

Comment: The div must be appended to li element, in you example it is appended to ul.